Calling user groups facebook graph API returns empty data
I'm making a following API call to facebook graph API to fetch user groups but it returns empty data array.
In the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/ I found out that:

As of April 4, 2018, this edge returns empty data sets for GET
operations unless the calling app has gone through App Review. This
applies to GET operations using /me/groups as well. Please see the
Groups API section of the Breaking Changes changelog for more
information.

I just started developing new app, so there is nothing to review yet. Is there a way to call this endpoint without app review process?
calling this endpoint:
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/me/groups?access_token=EAAP..."

returns empty data:
{
  "data": [
  ]
}

